# Creating an exe file in vs2012 express without installer

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I created a Windows Desktop Application. It is set to release in the project properties. All the Assembly info is filled in under the application tab. I have run rebuild, clean and run code analysis and all completes with no errors or warnings. I can copy the exe file from the release folder to another location and use it with no problem. 
   But when I look at the application with Microsoft process explorer it does not have any description or company name and when I hover over the process it says [Error opening process].

How do I get the Assembly info into the exe. I do not want to create an installer. I want to simply run the exe from whichever location I copy it to.

Also I have noticed that if I attempt to publish the solution vs Express automatically turns on One-click and gives me an error because I need to requireAdministrator. I don't want to use one-click. even if I unclick it in the security tab it automatically selects it again if I publish. this is NOT a web application. It is being created in the visual studio express 2012 for windows Desktop. and is a desktop application
thanks

Comment: 'Publish' in the context of VS simply means 'Make a Click-Once installation'- that's why that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. File version information is embedded into your executable has nothing to do with an installer.  If it exists, it's part of the file's resources.
2. Are you SURE that your Process Explorer is running with administrative rights?
3. Have you tried to look at the properties of the .exe file itself?  It should show the embedded resource information under the "details" tab.

If you filled out the assembly info, AND the file built without errors.. you already probably have what you are looking for.

Good luck.